# Is there a way to change the size of wchar_t in a Rust static library?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use Rust in an existing embedded C project on a M0+ micro-controller. I am using the Keil IDE to compile the code.

I can get a `lib.a` static library to generate, but when I try to compile it into my project I get an error saying that it can't link because

> ... wchart-16 clashes with wchart-32.

Because this is an existing project, I cannot change the size of `wchar_t` that is being used.

Is there a way to change the size of a `wchar_t` to use 16 bits in the compiled Rust library?

#### Files

**lib.rs**

```
#![no_std]

extern crate panic_halt; 

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rust_function() {

}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
# package info is here

[dependencies]
panic-halt = "0.2.0"

[lib]
name = "app_interface"
crate-type = ["staticlib"] # Creates static lib
```

**cargo\config**

```
[target.thumbv7m-none-eabi]

[target.'cfg(all(target_arch = "arm", target_os = "none"))']

rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-Tlink.x",
]

[build]
target = "thumbv6m-none-eabi"
```

Comment: `I try to compile it into my project` - please post all the steps needed to reproduce the problem. So, what `cargo` command are you executing? Are you trying to include generated static library into another project? How?